# Install or update appium-gestures-plugin required for W3c Actions/Gestures implementation when using Appium 2.0

Tags: plugins, appium, npm-install, gesture

I am using Appium2.0.0-beta66 version. Since **TouchAction** class being used for the gesture/actions is being deprecated,  I am supposed to install **appium-gestures-plugin** ([from](https://github.com/AppiumTestDistribution/appium-gestures-plugin) ) and use it.

When I try to run the command

```
appium plugin install --source=npm appium-gestures-plugin
```

as was suggested, I am getting the message

```
✔ Installing 'appium-gestures-plugin'
Error: ✖ A plugin named "gestures" is already installed. Did you mean to update?
```

I tried to check the installed plugins

```
$appium plugin list --installed
```

✔ Listing installed plugins

- relaxed-caps@1.0.0-beta.13 [installed (npm)]
- images@1.3.7 [installed (npm)]
- execute-driver@2.0.6 [installed (npm)]
- gestures@1.0.0-beta.4 [installed (npm)]

***How to update the existing 'gestures@1.0.0-beta.4' to gestures@2.0.0 ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got the answer that I have to use the option '--unsafe' to update from gestures@1.0.0-beta4 plugin to gestures@2.0. This is being enforced by the plugin itself, because ver2.0, has breaking changes.

```
  $appium plugin update gestures --unsafe
```